# Calculate number of milliseconds until next occurence of a time

Tags: c#

I feel like this is something really simple, but my Google Fu is letting me down as I keep finding difference calculations.

I have a time (e.g. 1800 hours) stored in a `DateTime` object. The date is null and immaterial. All I want to know is how many milliseconds until the NEXT occurrence of that time.

So, if I run the calculation at 0600 - it will return 12 hours (in ms). At 1750, it will return ten minutes (in ms) and at 1900 it will return 24 hours (in ms).

All the things I can find show me how to calculate differences, which doesn't work once you're past the time.

Here is what I tried, but fails once you're past the time and gives negative values:

```
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = _shutdownTime.TimeOfDay - nowTime.TimeOfDay;
double result = difference.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: [`TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx)

Comment: BTW, the date is *not* null and immaterial because it may be midnight and there may be a scheduled DST change on that day.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean by that? And you say you have found code that shows how to calculate differences, can you show that code?

Comment: Sorry guys, hit submit too early. My current code is now in the question

Comment: @Jon That's a fair point. I guess what I mean is that the time in question, which is a user setting, configures a daily event. Perhaps I should be not storing that in DateTime format?

Comment: So what is the problem with the code in question? It will correctly tell you how many milliseconds there is until the time, *or*, how many milliseconds there is *since* the time (but the value will be negative). What is the question?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Because I need to know how long until the *next* occurrence. So, for example, if I run that code it 1810 it gives me -10 minutes (in ms), which is useless to me.

Comment: No it isn't. If the next occurrence is defined as "the next occurrence *today*, or the next occurrence *tomorrow* if we're already past that time today", then that value is obviously not useless. It is exactly how long it is *if you add 24 hours to it*. In other words, if the value is positive, that's how long it is until the correct time *today*. If it is negative, add 24 hours (`TimeSpan.FromHours(24)`), and that's how long it is until the correct time *tomorrow*.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah, I hadn't thought of that. Yes, adding 24 hours does work. I've half realised my confusion though - which is that I presumed creating a DateTime object with just a time would mean I could ignore the Date portion, but this appears to be false. Is there a better way to store and work with a generic, non date specific time?

Comment: Use `TimeSpan`? But then, you're already using that, since `TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan`. The problem here is that you're asking .NET to subtract 18:00 hours from 14:00 hours, and expect it to come out with a *positive difference*. That's not going to happen. You need to deal with the scenario that the time has already passed and ask it to calculate it for the next day, which, as I pointed out, you can do by simply adding 24 hours to the result if it is negative.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If that's an "accepted" way of doing it, then that's fine and I'm happy with that. Copy your comment to an answer and I'll mark accordingly when I can.

Comment: @Dan: I have added an answer that accounts for DST changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already doing everything you should, except for one thing: handling negative results.

If the result is negative, it means the time you want to calculate the duration *until* has already passed, and then you want it to mean "tomorrow" instead, and get a positive value.

In this case, simply add 24 hours:

```
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = _shutdownTime.TimeOfDay - nowTime.TimeOfDay;
double result = difference.TotalMilliseconds;
if (result < 0)
    result += TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds;
```

The next thing to consider is this: If the time you want to calculate the duration until is 19:00 hours, and the current time is *exactly* 19:00 hours, do you want it to return 0 (zero) or 24 hours worth of time? Meaning, do you really want the *next* such occurrence?

If so, then change the above `if`-statement to use `<=`:

```
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = _shutdownTime.TimeOfDay - nowTime.TimeOfDay;
double result = difference.TotalMilliseconds;
if (result <= 0)
    result += TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds;
```

However, note that this will be prone to the usual problems with floating point values. If the current time is 18:59:59.9999999, do you still want it to return the current time (a minuscule portion of time) until 19:00 today, or do you want it to flip to tomorrow? If so, change the comparison to be slightly different:

```
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = _shutdownTime.TimeOfDay - nowTime.TimeOfDay;
double result = difference.TotalMilliseconds;
if (result <= -0.0001)
    result += TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds;
```

where `-0.0001` is a value that corresponds to "the range of inaccuracy you're prepared to accept being *tomorrow* instead of *today* in terms of milliseconds".

Comment: That's fantastic - I really appreciate your time on this

Comment: This approach is not always correct because of DST. In general, whenever you find yourself adding fixed timespans to a `DateTime` you are writing a DST bug.

Comment: Since he is specifically only dealing with time, I would say that is a non-issue, but you are of course right if you involve dates. Also note that I'm not actually adding fixed timespans to a DateTime, I'm adding it do a different TimeSpan, but that's semantics, the problem here, in terms of your comment, is the *minus* sign.

Comment: I'd say that if you try to deal with DST and the .NET date and time types, you're just going to write bugs [no matter what](http://noda-time.blogspot.no/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

Comment: Actually, if you convert local time to UTC and do all your calculations with UTC dates, you can avoid those problems. Local time should be only for input and output. Internally, *always* work with UTC. The conversions will handle the DST problems.

Comment: @JimMischel: Exactly. I am adding an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

When doing calculations like this it is important to take possible DST changes under consideration so that your results remain correct.

Suppose your operational parameters are:

```
var shutdownTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(18);
// just to illustrate, in Europe there is a DST change on 2013-10-27
// normally you 'd just use DateTime.Now here
var now = new DateTime(2013, 10, 26, 20, 00, 00);

// do your calculations in local time
var nextShutdown = now.Date + shutdownTime;
if (nextShutdown < now) {
    nextShutdown = nextShutdown.AddDays(1);
}

// when you want to calculate time spans in absolute time
// (vs. wall clock time) always convert to UTC first
var remaining = nextShutdown.ToUniversalTime() - now.ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine(remaining);
```

The answer to your question would now be `remaining.TotalMilliseconds`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This should be immaterial for my purposes (Famous last words), but it's good to know.